# How to retrieve LinkedIn video posts?

Tags: python-2.7, linkedin-api

I am trying to get LinkedIn video post from my company page. I have tried both V1 and V2 APIs.

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:company:<companyID>&sharesPerOwner=100&oauth2_access_token=<token>
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/<companyID>/updates?format=json&count=40&oauth2_access_token=<token>
```

I can see only photo posts and normal status updates. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video posts are available via the UGC Post API. You can make a GET request using:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List({encoded personURN})`

Comment: Can i use this API for companies also ?

Comment: I have tried this API and it is not working. Am getting error message : {"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.linkedin.data.DataComplex","status":500}

Comment: The documentation states both person and organization URNs will be accepted parameters on October 8:

Note: Starting October 8, 2018, the query parameter authors will be required and will start accepting organizationURN as a valid value.

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/ugc-post-api#get-authors

Comment: I will wait and check.

Comment: Still it is not working. I have tried below APIs. Any help ?                                                           https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=urn:li:organization:<companyID>&oauth2_access_token=<token>
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn:li:organization:<companyID>)&oauth2_access_token=<token>

Comment: @HegdeAvin please include your API request, as well as the response.

Comment: I have tried in 2 ways. ""API Request: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=urn:li:organization:<ORG_ID>&oauth2_access_token=<token>
Response: {"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"java.lang.ClassCastException","status":500}
API Request: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<ORG_ID>)&oauth2_access_token=<token>
Response:{"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"java.lang.ClassCastException","status":500}""

Comment: Have you defined the X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0 header with your request?

Comment: I have included "X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0" header and now it is working !! Thank you so much